# What queue can be used for IPC between Python and C?

Tags: python, c, queue

I want to use a queue for IPC between Python and C, where C is the main process and Python is the child process created by fork-execv.  The queue is created in C.

I see multiprocessing.Queue, multiprocessing.Manager.Queue, queue.queue and asyncio.queue.  In my research I haven't found any way for Python to join a queue created in a non-Python process such as C.  All examples show a queue created in Python.

My queue created in C with mq_open is named /MQ_01.  I want Python to join that queue by that name.  How can Python do that?

I would strongly prefer not to use a third-party library like ZeroMQ.  Is it possible to use just one of the Python queues in the scenario I described.

Thanks.

Comment: Some quick searching found this for working with posix message queues in python: http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/

Comment: Thanks, Shawn.  It looks good, but I'm trying to avoid any third-party libraries or extensions that aren't part of Python because I'm distributing my app to many end users, and I can't require them to have anything non-Python installed.

Comment: Well, if you want to use posix message queues, you have to use it because python doesn't support them in its standard library.

Comment: how do you run the python process from C? I recommend using [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). this way you can embed most of the python execution within c commands